# Automatic CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_ON fields in SQL SERVER 2008 table (without using triggers)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, auditing

I'm looking for a way to store the date/time a row was updated, inserted, who inserted/updated it (the db user account) that does not rely on triggers in SQL Server 2008. Is this possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: you can use table default for Created_by and Created_on. you can updated_by and Updated_on using tsql code (function or store proc. )

Comment: For updates, you NEED to use triggers.  For inserts you can use `DEFAULT` constraints.  Why are you opposed to triggers?

Comment: Why exactly you don't want to use triggers? Sounds like a good situation to use them.

Comment: The only real alternative to triggers I think will be controlling all inserts/updates/deletes through stored procs that record that data for you.

Comment: @JNK Or some other way of wrapping the business logic... UDF?

Comment: You can use CDC(change data capture) to track all changes.